# jquery droppable with different area

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

***droppable issues***

first I will drop a form its containment is div and will set counter that increment form 'Id' by dropping its again and again, after it I will drop another element through on form that will appear in form . Now for other element dropping my containment is form. It works but the element will appear in each form.

> I want that it will appear in only one form where I want to drop.

here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col l6">
      <ul class="form" data-page="form">
          <li>
             <p>form</p>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="dragme" data-page="question">
         <li>
            <p>question</p>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="dragme" data-page="checkbox">
         <li>
            <p>checkbox</p>
         </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col l6">
      <div class="form-container">

           //form droppable area
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 0;

    $('.form').draggable({
       conectToSortable: 'form-container',
       containment: 'form-container',
       helper: 'clone',
       revert: 'invalid',
    start:function(){
       $('.form-container').droppable();
       $('.cont').sortable();
    },
    stop: function(){
      var page = $(this).attr('data-page');
    $.ajax({
      url:'http://form.html';
      success:function(data){
      counter = counter + 1;
      data = data.replace('abc',counter);
      $('.form-container').append(data);
      }
    });
   },
 });
});

$('.dragme').draggable({
   conectToSortable: 'form-element',
   containment: 'form-child',
   helper: 'clone',
   revert: 'invalid',
 start:function(){
    $('.form-child').droppable();
    $('.form-child').sortable();
  }, 
 stop: function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('data-page');
    $.ajax({
    url:'http://other-pages';
       success:function(data){
        $().append(data);
        $('.form-container').append(data);
       } 
     })
    },
   });
  });

</script>
```

form will call from another page . Here is the code:

```
 <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
    <form>
       <div id="abc" class="form-element form-child">

            //droppable area for other element

        </div>
    <form>
 </div>
```

[I will drop it in one from but appear also in other form...I want it in one thats will dropped...how can I do it please help 
thanks in advance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1uzK.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have a number of JavaScript Syntax errors. Two in your `$.ajax()` portion, where a `;` is being used when `,` is expected.

Comment: It appears you attempted to edit my answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 0):

I started with some code cleanup:

```js
$(function() {

  var counter = 0;

  $('.form').draggable({
    conectToSortable: 'form-container',
    containment: 'form-container',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function(e, ui) {
      $('.form-container').droppable();
      $('.cont').sortable();
    },
    stop: function() {
      var page = $(this).attr('data-page');
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://form.html',
        success: function(data) {
          counter++;
          $('.form-container').append(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $('.dragme').draggable({
    conectToSortable: 'form-element',
    containment: 'form-child',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function() {
      $('.form-child').droppable();
      $('.form-child').sortable();
    },
    stop: function() {
      var page = $(this).attr('data-page');
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://other-pages',
        success: function(data) {
          counter++;
          $('.form-container').append(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col l6">
    <ul class="form" data-page="form">
      <li>
        <p>form</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dragme" data-page="question">
      <li>
        <p>question</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dragme" data-page="checkbox">
      <li>
        <p>checkbox</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col l6">
    <div class="form-container">
      //form droppable area
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code does not really do anything though since it's all AJAX. In addition to that, your droppables don't have anything script for them when you drop something to them. Since your example is not complete, it's really hard to determine what should be the expected result.

I would advise setting your droppables much like your draggables and then disabling them or resetting their `accept` option. This will allow them to be properly initialized when the page loads and also do whatever it is you want them to do.

Comment: "*you can see the image that data will appearing in both form but i want it in one how can we set append(data) to form that where drag and mouse down here will appear means appear in one*" Your comment is unclear. You will want to review Droppable examples: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/